# How to replace duplicate values with null in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image: In the same Subject ID, how to replace duplicate values in Age with NA according to the category of Visit? And retain the value of the first occurrence.]

its my code 

how to replace duplicate values in Age with NA according to the category of Visit? And retain the value of the first occurrence.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(data_path+'MRI.csv',encoding='utf-8'))
    # pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)
    df = df.set_index('Subject ID',drop=False)
    # get SubjectID
    suid = list(df['Subject ID'].unique())
    # creat a new DataFrame
    mri = pd.DataFrame()
    # use pd.groupby()
    grouped = df.groupby('Subject ID')
    for id in suid:
        group = grouped.get_group(id)
        temp = group.duplicated(['Age']).astype(int)
        # Insert temp after 'Age' as the sign of 'Age'
        group.insert(7, 'temp',temp)
        # Replace the value in 'Age' with the value of 'temp'
        for index, row in group.iterrows():
           if row['temp'] == 1:
               group.loc[index, 'Age'] = np.nan
        print(group)
        break
```

after the replacement, the all value of 'Age' becomes NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
df.loc[df.Visit.duplicated(), 'Age']=np.nan
```

**Input**

```
   Visit    Age
0   ADNI    42
1   ADNI    42
2   ADNI    42
3   ADNI    42
4   BDNI    34
5   BDNI    34
6   BDNI    34
7   BDNI    34
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
   Visit    Age
0   ADNI    42.0
1   ADNI    NaN
2   ADNI    NaN
3   ADNI    NaN
4   BDNI    34.0
5   BDNI    NaN
6   BDNI    NaN
7   BDNI    NaN
```